# Application properties for a struts2 java web application

Tags: java, properties, configuration, struts2, app-config

I am new to Struts2 framework and I am trying to add some configuration properties like `applicationId`, `timeout` etc which will be used for calling some 3rd party APIs. In a Springboot project, we usually keep the `application.properties/application.yml` file and we are able to access the values using the `@Value` or `@ConfigurationProperties` annotations, what is the equivalent functionality in Struts2? Also, is it secure to store these keys in a property file(no passwords only unique identifiers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struts2 keeps it's configuration in the `struts.xml` or `struts.properties` files that have loaded and parced on application startup. These properties can be accessible everywhere in you application, even via dependency injection.

But there's another way to configure your actions with properties files. It's known as Message Resource properties. You can configure them either in `struts.xml` or `struts.properties` file. The key/values are loaded via the

> Within action classes that extend `ActionSupport` through the `getText()` method

There's a lot of places and properties where you can configure. Everything about it is described in the [Localization Guide](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/localization.html).

For your purpose you can use global properties, or custom text provider.

> Global Resources (`struts.custom.i18n.resource`s) in `struts.properties`
> A global resource bundle could be specified programmatically, as well as the locale.
>
> Comparison with Struts 1
> Struts 1 users should be familiar with the `application.properties` resource bundle, where you can put all the messages in the application that are going to be translated. Struts 2, though, splits the resource bundles
>
> Using only global bundles
> If you don’t need to use the package-scan-functionality and only base on the global bundles (those provided by the framework and via `struts.custom.i18n.resources`) you can use existing `GlobalLocalizedTextProvider` implementation. To use this please define the following option in your `struts.xml`:
>
> ```
> <constant name="struts.localizedTextProvider" value="global-only" />
> ```
>
> Custom `TextProvider` and `TextProviderFactory`
> If you want to use a different logic to search for localized messages, or you want to use a database or just want to search default bundles, you must implement both those interfaces (or subclass the existing implementations). You can check a small example app how to use both. Please remember that the `TextProvider`.

Comment: You can also upvote this answer. It will help others to find a better solution.